# opencv 3.4.1 error: Assertion failed (chunk.m_size <= 0xFFFF) in readFrame

Tags: video-capture, opencv3.0

I used same code and the same video and tested on the two environment.At first I tested on the "Opencv3.1.0 + windows(ubuntu) + VS2015",there is no error.But when I use the "opencv3.4.1+ MacOS + Clion", I got the error:

```
Unexpected list type. Expected: hdrl. Got: movi.
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (chunk.m_size <= 0xFFFF) in readFrame, file /tmp/opencv-20180307-60086-ryy1b3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/videoio/src/container_avi.cpp, line 514
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.1) /tmp/opencv-20180307-60086-ryy1b3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/videoio/src/container_avi.cpp:514: error: (-215) chunk.m_size <= 0xFFFF in function readFrame
```

Test code :

```
VideoCapture cap("test.avi");
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout << "error" << endl;
    return -1;
}
Mat img;
double rate = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
cout << rate << endl;
int total_rate = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
cout << total_rate << endl;
while (true) {
    if(!cap.read(img)) break;
}
```

How to fix the problem and why? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution but, changing the extension ".avi" with ".mp4" or ".mkv" mades the job for me. Problem might be with opencv lib

Comment: Problem occurred because of the version of opencv. Version 3.4.1 add a new assertion in file container_avi.cpp. [#issue11126](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11126) is where I find the reason.So I remove the assertion and rebuild the opencv to solve the problem. And thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV version upto 3.4 has this problem with reading AVI file formats. Try using a later version to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a bug in OpenCV version that you are using. You should probably use a different version.